# Creating an array of clients

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

For my select boxes switching, I need to pre-build a javascript array for the select option values by using php to generate a js array on load. I have done this until now by creating an object and adding it to an array, but now I need one of the object's properties to be an array of years. I'm close (the object's clientForm property will return a csv list if I document.write it), but I don't think it's an array as I can't access the length property and the previous document.write doesn't output array. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or suggest an alternative method?

Here is the php which outputs the Javascript array (I've built the system in CodeIgniter):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            $array = 'var companies = new Array();';
$i = 0;foreach($clientList as $client) :
                $array .= 'arrayItem'.$i.' = {clientNo:"'.$client->client_id.'", clientCompany:"'.$client->client_company_name.'", clientRef:"'.$client->client_ref_no.'", clientForms: Array(';
                if($client->client_forms != "")
                {

                    $a = 0; foreach($client->client_forms as $form) :
                        $array .= $form.", ";
                    ++$a; endforeach;

                }
                $array = substr($array, 0, -2); 
                $array .= ')};';
                $array .= 'companies['.$i.'] = arrayItem'.$i.'; ';
++$i; endforeach;
            echo $array;
            echo '</script>';
```

And here is the current output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var companies = new Array();
    arrayItem0 = {clientNo:"1", clientCompany:"Test1", clientRef:"UG123HS", clientForms: Array(1, 15)};
    companies[0] = arrayItem0;

    arrayItem1 = {clientNo:"2", clientCompany:"Test2", clientRef:"UF321HS", clientForms: Array(17)};
    companies[1] = arrayItem1;
</script>
```

If you want a look, here is the full outputted code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phily245/TDRxQ/) (jsfiddle can't seem to make my onclicks work, but they do on the actual webpage).

Thanks!

Comment: Create usual PHP array, and then json_encode it. I think it would be much easier.

Comment: `json_encode`ing is the best solution as it seems to me...got for it

Answer (score 1):

To create an array, you're better of using this syntax: `clientForms: [1,15]`

Or else don't forget to add `new`: `clientForms: new Array(1,15)`

Answer (score 1):

You're code doesn't look too far off, since jsFiddle isn't working too well, it's hard to tell.  I did notice one thing however.

Where you have `list.options[i+1]=new Option(companies[i].clientCompany, companies[i].clientRef, false, false); //Add the first option in` you should probably have `list.options[cnt+1]=new Option(companies[i].clientCompany, companies[i].clientRef, false, false); //Add the first option in`

Notice I changed the first `i` to `cnt`.  `i` is the counter for stepping through the array and `cnt` is actually your option counter.  You could have very potentially been leaving blank options if your actual page didn't produce results with every array item.

EDIT:

This was in the function replaceCompanySelect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mashington and @ParthThakkar for the answer, I wasn't aware of how json_encode() in PHP and JSON.parse() in javascript could work together. here is my new php code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "var companies = JSON.parse('".json_encode($clientList)."');";
echo '</script>';
```